# why does (10 + (-inf)) results in -inf?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I tried to add `float('-inf')` and `10` in python, as per my knowledge `-inf` is smaller than all other values.

So if I add `-inf` and `10` it should give `10` as an answer. Rather than giving `10` as an output it is giving `-inf`.

Is `-inf` bigger than `10`?

Comment: Why do you think that "`-inf` is smaller than all other numbers" implies "`-inf + 10` equals 10"?

Comment: Infinity is not a real number, it is an idea. The only thing that you can add 10 to in order to equal 10 is 0.

Comment: @Terry, that may be true in maths, it's not necessarily so with computers that don't have infinite storage capacity: `double d = 10; d += 10e-308; if (d == 10) printf ("equal\n");` gives "equal" :-)

Comment: @TerryA that's not true at all in floating point arithmetic. For example, many of the denormalized floats when added to 10 give 10. Also -0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-inf` *is* the smallest number but what that means is that it's the negative number with the *largest* magnitude. It *doesn't* mean it's the closest you can get to zero without actually being zero (i.e., the smallest *positive* number):

```
<---------------------------|-------------------------->
-inf                        0   10                   +inf
```

When you add a massive negative number to 10, you'll still end up with a massive negative number. That's the same idea as with `-inf`, other than the fact infinity is not a real number.

Answer (score 5):

`-inf` means negative infinity.  It is "smaller" than all other values in that it is less than them.  Adding negative infinity to any finite number still gives negative infinity.

Comment: Also I have one  more question, float() is one function to be used to create floating point values, but still we are using it to create Nan,-INF and INF. So is it possible to use int() in the same way? if it no then why?

Comment: @SelvaMathan: No, because the `int` datatype doesn't have any way to represent those values.  The fact that `float` does is really just an artifact of underlying floating-point implementations.

Comment: @SelvaMathan Most languages follow the [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for floats, that's what defines things like `NaN`, `+∞` and `−∞`(Though Python is not following it properly ;-)).